# RAII Locking with std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex); instead of std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_mutex);

Tags: c++, locking, thread-synchronization

It's probably a stupid question, but I discovered a few occurences of a lock_guard without variable.

```
void func() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
  m_value = "2";
}
```

Instead of the following with lk variable.

```
void func() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_mutex);
  m_value = "2";
}
```

The first version is probably bullshit and causes the access to be in some kind of soft sync mode, since the lock is held for a short moment, so no longer running function holds the lock currently, right?

Or did I learn something here and lk variable is actually not required?

Comment: Note use std::scope_guard, instead of std::lock_guard

Comment: TLDR: yes, it's required. Fire up your debugger, and step through both versions of the code, one line at a time. You will see exactly when the mutex gets locked and unlocked.

Comment: It's C++11. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex);` creates a temporary object and immediately destroys it. The lock doesn't last beyond this statement.

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex);` is a bug

Comment: I think the first option is plain wrong. It creates a temporary that will go out of scope at the same line.

Comment: there are no "stupid" questions, though this one lacks context. Where did you see such code?

Comment: See [`std::lock_guard` Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard#Notes) _"... A common beginner error is to "forget" to give a lock_guard variable a name ... thereby not actually constructing a lock that holds a mutex for the rest of the scope."_

Comment: @PeteBecker It's disambiguated as a declaration with a parenthesized declarator. Then fails for lack of default constructor.

Comment: @xeed The first code example wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows you why it is wrong :

```
#include <iostream>

struct raii_class
{
    raii_class()
    {
        std::cout << "raii construct\n";
    }
    ~raii_class()
    {
        std::cout << "raii destruct\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    raii_class{};
    std::cout << "body\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs :

```
raii construct
raii destruct
body
```